# IoT device that use iPhone as Gateway

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, iot

I'm developing an IoT device that will connect to iOS via Bluetooth.
I've seen some smartwatches that uses the iPhone as a gateway to perform Internet connection tasks like getting weather data, without the need to open a particular app.
How can this be achieved? 
Is there any supported Bluetooth Profile that iOS support for that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to allow you to listen to Bluetooth activities in the background as well. Check out this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html).

And, for the part about running tasks without the app running in the foreground, you might want to check out the [background execution API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks) (Only in iOS 13)